# FPDF break page error

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf

i'm developin an app that sholud create a pdf document with more than one page, my problem is that i found the way to add pages when needen but after the break page it doesn't write.

So the result is a pdf with 8 pages where 7 are blank and only one, the first page that in the document is the last, is correctly writed.

**THIS IS MY CODE:**

```
$pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);
    $pdf->SetXY(20,20);
    $pdf->AcceptPageBreak();
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
    //PDF content before table
    $pdf->Write(14,"Resoconto dell'applicazione EBI dell'ultimo mese:");
    $pdf_table=new FPDF_Table($pdf);
    //$pdf_table->setDefaultCellWidth(50);
    //echo "<br>";
    //echo "------------------------------------------- <br>";
    $i=0;
    $righe=0;
    while (...) {
        if ($righe % 20 === 0) {
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);
            $pdf->SetXY(20,20);
        }
        $righe++;
        $pdf->Write(...);
    }
```

How can i solve this?

Thank's

Comment: What are you asking? You're only writing once and it's outside the loop so of course all other pages will be blank?

Comment: Sorry, now i edit the code in the question, i write inside the loop @h2ooooooo